# Does R clear memory used by sequence after execution

Tags: r, memory, seq

So as the title suggests, I'm wondering if memory used by `seq` is made available again after execution, for instance `seq(0,100000,0.01)`

Comment: R will store the results in a variable `.Last.value`, so the memory used from `seq(0,100000,0.01)` won't be freed up until you run another command

Comment: @DiceboyT is this true even when a command is run to store a value in a variable, such as `foo <- 42`

Comment: @JonathanRauscher yes, but the memory address will be the same as `foo`

Comment: @DiceboyT if you add your comment as an answer I'll be happy to mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R will store the results in a variable `.Last.value`, so the memory used from `seq(0,100000,0.01)` won't be freed up until you run another command:

```
initial_memory <- sum(gc()[, "used"])

seq(0,100000,0.01)

# memory difference after running command
new_memory <- sum(gc()[, "used"])
new_memory - initial_memory
#> [1] 1e+07

# if we run again, we see memory return close to original
new_memory <- sum(gc()[, "used"])
new_memory - initial_memory
#> [1] -16
```